# Make Multiple Increment Buttons Work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have put together the following increment counter and have it running on a page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Click Counter</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='inc/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('body').on('click', 'button', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var currentNumber = $('#currentNumber').text();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'increase_counter.php',
        data: {currentNumber : currentNumber}
    })
    .done(function(newNumber){
        $('#currentNumber').text(newNumber);
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="currentNumber">[xyz-ips snippet="Counter"]</div>
<button type="button">Click To Add One</button>
</body>
</html>
```

In tandem with the following php file on my server:

```
<?php
  $counter_name = 'emailCounter.txt';
  if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f,"0");
  fclose($f);
 }

  $counterVal = file_get_contents($counter_name);
  $counterVal++;

  $f = fopen($counter_name,"w");
  fwrite($f, $counterVal);
  fclose($f);

  echo $counterVal;
?>
```

It gives me an increment counter that increases the stored value in a .txt document on my server every time i click a button- by +1, and works perfectly.
However, I'd like to have more than one counter on the same page.
How do I put a distinct second button & counter in? (they will count a seperate thing).
I have created a second url 'increase_counter2.php' which will perform the generation of the second .txt file and also perform the calculation... just not sure how to set up to buttons on the page.

### EDIT - SOLUTION

For any who see this in the future

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Click Counter</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='inc/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('body').on('click', 'button', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var currentNumber = $('#currentNumber').text();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'increase_counter.php',
        data: {
counterId: event.target.id, // you get the button through the click
value: currentNumber
}
    })
    .done(function(newNumber){
        $('#currentNumber').text(newNumber);
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="currentNumber">[xyz-ips snippet="Counter2"]</div>
<button type="button" id="Counter1">Sheets</button>
<button type="button" id="Counter2">Pillow</button>
<button type="button" id="Counter3">King Sheet</button>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
if ( isset($_POST['counterId']) ) {
$counterId = $_POST['counterId'];

if ( !file_exists($countersFile) ) {
    $counters = [];
} else {
    $counters = json_decode(file_get_contents($countersFile), TRUE);
    if ( is_null($counters) ) $counters = [];
}

if ( array_key_exists($counterId, $counters) ) {
    $counters[$counterId]++;
} else {
    $counters[$counterId] = 1;
}

file_put_contents($countersFile,
    json_encode($counters, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),
    LOCK_EX);

echo $counters[$counterId];
}
?>
```

Comment: is it a requirement to write in *two* different files?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure as I'm very new to this. But they will be tracking seperate things so maybe

Answer (score 0):

i think if you like second counter in same page
try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.button', function(event){
    addnumber(1);
  });
  $('body').on('click', '.button1', function(event){
    addnumber(2);
  });
});
function addnumber(nom){
    var currentNumber = $('#currentNumber').text();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'increase_counter.php',
        data: {currentNumber : currentNumber,addno:nom}
    })
    .done(function(newNumber){
        $('#currentNumber').text(newNumber);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="currentNumber">[xyz-ips snippet="Counter"]</div>
<button type="button" class="button">Click To Add One</button>
<button type="button" class="button1">Click To Add Two</button>
```

increase_counter.php

```
<?php
  $counter_name = 'emailCounter.txt';
  if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f,"0");
  fclose($f);
 }

  $counterVal = file_get_contents($counter_name);
  $counterVal=$counterVal+$_POST['addno'];

  $f = fopen($counter_name,"w");
  fwrite($f, $counterVal);
  fclose($f);

  echo $counterVal;
?>
```

if you like a different counter page like emailCounter1.txt, emailCounter2.txt etc
change increase_counter.php to

```
<?php
  $counter_name1 = 'emailCounter1.txt';
  $counter_name2 = 'emailCounter2.txt';

  $no=$_POST['addno'];

  if (!file_exists($counter_name.$no)) {
  $f = fopen($counter_name.$no, "w");
  fwrite($f,"0");
  fclose($f);
 }

  $counterVal = file_get_contents($counter_name.$no);
  $counterVal=$counterVal+$_POST['addno'];

  $f = fopen($counter_name.$no,"w");
  fwrite($f, $counterVal);
  fclose($f);

  echo $counterVal;
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant two distinct counters, not a second counter that add's '2'.

Comment: They are counting different things

Answer (score 0):

You could change the representation of the data that is sent and save a JSON representation of it in the file. You must add id's to the buttons so you can uniquely identify counters.

```
data: {
    counterId: event.target.id, // you get the button through the click
    value: currentNumber
}
```

---

```
$counters = json_decode($json);
if (isset($_POST['counterId'])) {
    $counterId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'counterId', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'value', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $counters[$counterId] = $value;
}
$json = json_encode($counters);
```

Save to and read from the file that JSON string. Since the ids differ the values are kept track of. You also don't need to write another php file, for instance if you want to add a third button. (!)

Comment: Sorry I'm very new at this, I'm not quite sure where to put those snippets, or how to add the id's to the buttons!

Comment: adding id's is literally something you will find in the most basic html tutorial out there. as for the snippets, you literally can just replace them in your code (you have `data` in your code, surely you know where) and it will work almost at once. However, I'm not sure if you are studying or doing that for fun, but in both cases you will have to use your brain to make this work completely. If you don't want to then... find another hobby? ;) Joking aside, it's really basic javascript and DOM manipulation. read a few tutorials, it will start to make sense.

Comment: or, come hang out in the php chat room. there is way more in your question than can be answered here.

Comment: Yes please forgive me, I had never done any of this before 2 days ago. Everything i have so far is from trial and error haha. I added in the data line, and it works, but the second snippet doesn't seem to work. I'm getting the error "undefined variable on line 2" which is the line $counters = json_decode($json);

Comment: and I did the button id's like this: <button id="1" type="button">First Counter</button> <button id="2" type="button">Second Counter</button>

Comment: The exact error is "PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: json in increase_counter.php on line 2"